# Position: Sticky effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, position, conditional-statements, onscroll

I'm trying to write a simple script with pure JavaScript, which creates a position sticky effect. The code below works well for me.

```
var siteHeader = document.getElementById('siteHeader'),
    siteNav = document.getElementById('siteNav');

    window.onscroll = function() {
        if ( siteNav.offsetTop < document.documentElement.scrollTop + 26 || siteNav.offsetTop < document.body.scrollTop + 26) {
            siteHeader.setAttribute("class","sticky");
        }
        else {
            siteHeader.setAttribute("class","");
        }
    }
```

Is there a cleverer way of writing this line?

```
if ( siteNav.offsetTop < document.documentElement.scrollTop + 26 || siteNav.offsetTop < document.body.scrollTop + 26) {
```

I tried writing this but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

```
siteNav.offsetTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop + 26 : siteNav.offsetTop < document.body.scrollTop + 26
```

Apologies if the ternary condition looks stupid.

Comment: Yours looks good. Are there any particular problems you're running into with it? Or just want opinions on syntax?

Comment: That's how I would write it ... the Ternary operation doesn't fit well here.

Comment: I wouldn't hardcode a number `26` in the conditional, but instead keep that value in a variable declared up top in case you need to change it later.

Comment: I'd suggest using `$(el).outerHeight()` or similar instead of hard-coding `26`.

Comment: That wouldn't be pure JS anymore. But it might be a good idea, to put the 26 in a variable outside the scroll event. Makes it a bit more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @philtune: I was hoping more for a thoughtful solution on syntax.

Comment: @JonathanM: Thanks, can't believe I forgot to do that. Applied :)

Comment: @AndrewDunai
@Felix
Thanks guys. That seems a good idea. [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight) looks good :),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just the original code (amend from suggestions as you see fit...)

If you're only concerned about add/remove the "sticky" class...

```
siteHeader[siteNav < (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop + 26 ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("sticky");
```

-- EDIT --
Didn't notice the siteHeader is selected with vanilla JS...

```
siteHeader.setAttribute("class", 
    siteNav < (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop + 26 
        ? "sticky" : "");
```

Now, "clever" vs. readability is entirely subjective, but the logic should fit.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. I had to make a slight change to the code, which looks like this `siteNav.offsetTop < (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + requiredTopPosition ? "sticky" : "";`